# How to get reduced latency in gstreamer pipeline udpsrc

Tags: udp, gstreamer, nvidia, latency, imx6

I am streaming camera from imx6q platform on remote display which has NVIDIA GPU. I am  using below gstreamer pipeline on remote display to stream camera. In below pipeline we are using NVIDIA decoder plugin.

gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=0 drop-on-latency=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! nvdec ! glimagesink sync=false

with this pipeline we are getting ~116ms to ~175ms latency in camera streaming on remote display. How we can reduce our latency in video streaming. Is there any gstreamer plugin which can help us reduce latency or any other way.

Thanks